# Should I change Admob test id before submitting to Apple Certification Team for review? SwiftUI

Tags: admob, swiftui

Newbie here. I am about to submit my first app to the Apple store. I have an Admob banner in the app which I have been running with the test id Admob provided. On Admob page, they were suggesting using test id in order to prevent account suspension.

Now that I am submitting the app for approval should I change the test id to my ad unit id? Or wait for the app to be published after approval and update the app with my ad unit ad later?

Comment: you can just use your ad unit id because its the release of your app and it should be "as is". to get your account suspended you have to generate a lot of traffic / = money in ads, to make Google even notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added my ad unit id and did not encounter any problems.